# Is BigTable object oriented database?

Tags: database, google-app-engine, bigtable

I want to know that the distributed database system Bigtable is object oriented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. It is "a sparse, distributed multi-dimensional sorted map"

(source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable)

Answer (score 2):

No. It is a rather odd beast - see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Google's own research paper on the subject](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html). Good read.